Presence sensor to room with washing machine
I need a presence sensor:

for a small room (4m2).
should be able to turn on the light when someone enters and stays in the room.
needs to be recessed ceiling mounted
should not be triggered by the washer/dryer in the room.
My budget is 100 USD (I will purchase it in Poland).

I am concerned about false alarms caused by the heat emitted from the washer/dryer, so I'm hesitant about using a PIR sensor.
Can you recommend a type of sensor that would meet these requirements?
Also, if possible, could you suggest a specific model?

You can install something like this Leviton Occupancy Sensor

Hi jbro, thanks for you answer. Could you provide some reasons why you think the Leviton Occupancy Sensor is a good fit compared to other occupancy sensors?

This one specifically states support for 220v but other than that, no - they’re pretty much the same. One thing to consider is whether your present switch has a neutral or not. Here in US its not common, rather the switch typically stands between the hot source and light fixture.

Great, thanks! That doesn't look like it's recessed ceiling mounted though, and it also looks to be PIR based?
